# Calculate residual amount in dataframe column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have a "capacity" dataframe:

```
scala> sql("create table capacity (id String, capacity Int)");
scala> sql("insert into capacity values ('A', 50), ('B', 100)");
scala> sql("select * from capacity").show(false)

+---+--------+
|id |capacity|
+---+--------+
|A  |50      |
|B  |100     |
+---+--------+
```

I have another "used" dataframe with following information:

```
scala> sql ("create table used (id String, capacityId String, used Int)");
scala> sql ("insert into used values ('item1', 'A', 10), ('item2', 'A', 20), ('item3', 'A', 10), ('item4', 'B', 30), ('item5', 'B', 40), ('item6', 'B', 40)")
scala> sql("select * from used order by capacityId").show(false)

+-----+----------+----+
|id   |capacityId|used|
+-----+----------+----+
|item1|A         |10  |
|item3|A         |10  |
|item2|A         |20  |
|item6|B         |40  |
|item4|B         |30  |
|item5|B         |40  |
+-----+----------+----+
```

Column "capacityId" of the "used" dataframe is foreign key to column "id" of the "capacity" dataframe. 
I want to calculate the "capacityLeft" column which is residual amount at that point of time.

```
+-----+----------+----+--------------+
|id   |capacityId|used| capacityLeft |
+-----+----------+----+--------------+
|item1|A         |10  |40            |  <- 50(capacity of 'A')-10
|item3|A         |10  |30            |  <- 40-10
|item2|A         |20  |10            |  <- 30-20
|item6|B         |40  |60            |  <- 100(capacity of 'B')-40
|item4|B         |30  |30            |  <- 60-30
|item5|B         |40  |-10           |  <- 30-40
+-----+----------+----+--------------+
```

In real senario, the "createdDate" column is used for ordering of "used" dataframe column.

> Spark version:  2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using [window functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html) in Spark. Note that for this to work there need to exist a column that keep track of the row order for each `capacityId`.

Start by joining the two dataframes together:

```
val df = used.join(capacity.withColumnRenamed("id", "capacityId"), Seq("capacityId"), "inner")
```

Here the id in the `capacity` dataframe is renamed to match the id name in the `used` dataframe as to not keep a duplicate columns.

Now create a window and calculate the cumsum of the used column. Take the value of the `capacity` and subtract the cumsum to get the remaining amount:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("capacityId").orderBy("createdDate")
val df2 = df.withColumn("capacityLeft", $"capacity" - sum($"used").over(w))
```

Resulting dataframe with example `createdDate` column:

```
+----------+-----+----+-----------+--------+------------+
|capacityId|   id|used|createdDate|capacity|capacityLeft|
+----------+-----+----+-----------+--------+------------+
|         B|item6|  40|          1|     100|          60|
|         B|item4|  30|          2|     100|          30|
|         B|item5|  40|          3|     100|         -10|
|         A|item1|  10|          1|      50|          40|
|         A|item3|  10|          2|      50|          30|
|         A|item2|  20|          3|      50|          10|
+----------+-----+----+-----------+--------+------------+
```

Any unwanted columns can now be removed with `drop`.

Comment: Thanks. It is giving me desired output.